# How to determine the most repeated values into a interval of a vector array matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, find

this is my question:

I want to know which and how many times is a value repeated in a interval of a vector array, I know that many people will tell me that use "hist", but I did it and the results isn't exact enough, let me show you in a picture my problem:

[image]

In the past picture, you can see in blue the "Data"; and I have used 3 kinds of values: 1st "Mode", 2nd "Mean" and finally "Most repeated value in Histogram" which means that I used something like [a,b]=hist(Data), then Mayor Value = b(a==max(a)) and is very important to do NOT use a **predefined range**; but this picture doesn't represent the most repeted values, so let me show you another pic, which is a closer view of the data:

[image]

That blue "Data", which vary between (0-0.5)E-5 approximately is the interval that I need to obtain, but as you can see, the others three values are not close enough. And "mode" value is just "0". I hope that you can help me to solve this problem, thanks by the way!.

Ok to be more clear, I add this new pic:

[image]

What exactly I'm looking for is to get an **interval**, like in this example I wrote manually 0.1 - 0.4 E-4 (in purple), so the function will say:

[A,B]=magicfunction(Data);

A=[0.1E-4 0.4E-4]; B=[123];

Where **B=123** means the amount of data contained in that interval, as you can see I just ingress vector "Data", nothing else.

In the next link you can get the "Data": 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4WGV21GqSL5Vk0tRUdLNk5XVnc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, judging by the first graph, it seems clear that the most frequent value is 0, so `mode` is doing what it should. What would you expect instead? Does `mode(Data(Data>0))` give you a better result?

Comment: Are you looking for a "most frequent value", or an interval where your data values are most likely to be?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, and I need an "interval" NOT a single value. But it's clear that I don't want predefine any initial interval to make the search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isn't taking the max of a hist in a range what you want? you almost got it, you just didn't define the bins well. For example:

```
 range=4750:5050;
 [counts val]=hist(data(range),unique(data(range)));
 most_repeated _value_in_range=val(counts==max(counts));
```

### Edit:

Following the clarification, what you want is a statistical bound regarding the histogram width around it's maximum (most frequent value) , here's a solution:

```
[c, v]=hist(data,linspace(min(data),max(data),num_of_bins));
range=find(c>1/exp(1)*max(c)); % can be also c>0.5*max(c) etc...
A=[v(range(1)) v(range(end))];
B=sum(c(range));
```

Let's test with some fake data:

```
t=linspace(-50,50,1e3);
data=0.3*exp(-(t-30).^2)+0.2*exp(-(t-10).^2)+0.3*exp(-(t+10).^2)+0.01*randn(1,numel(t));

[c, v]=hist(data,linspace(min(data),max(data),numel(t)));
range=find(c>1/exp(1)*max(c));
A=[v(range(1)) v(range(end))];
B=sum(c(range));

plot(t,data,'b'); hold on
plot([min(t) max(t)],[A(1) A(1)] ,'--r');
plot([min(t) max(t)],[A(2) A(2)] ,'--r');
B
```

[image]

```
B =

   518
```

Of course you can change the definition of "width" of the histogram, I took 1/e to 1/e you can take full width at half max (`c>0.5*max(c)`), or narrower according to the type of data used, etc...

Comment: No, by now it's taking the max of the result of function "hist" without any predefined interval.

Comment: the predefined interval is given by `range`, it takes the max only in that range.

Comment: Yes @natan I know it, but the thing is that I don't have to set a "range".

Comment: do you mean, you want this to be a function of range so you can do something like `f(range)` and get the most repeated value? please try to be more clear in why this is not what you want.

Comment: look the description again, I have added something.

Answer (score 1):

The function below is designed based on several assumptions:

- The "interval" of interest is close to 0.
- The majority of the samples are small.

The basic idea is to first filter out the samples that are too big, and then define the interval based on the sorted array of the remaining samples.

```
function [A, B] = magicfunction(data)

% Assuming the outlier samples only exist in the positive side, some 
% samples of big, positive values can be excluded in order to obtain a 
% better estimation of "the interval". Here we exclude the
% samples that are greater than mean(A)+K1*std(A), where K1 is empirically
% selected as 1.0
K1 = 1.0;
filtered_data = data( data < mean(data)+K1*std(data)); 
sorted_data = sort(filtered_data);

% Define the interval in terms of the percentile in the
% sorted_data. Here the interval is empirically selected as [0, 0.75]
interval = [0 0.75];

% Map the percentile interval to the actual index in sorted_data.
% Note that interval_index(1) cannot be smaller than 1, and
% interval_index(2) cannot be greater than length(sorted_data)
interval_index = round( length(sorted_data)*interval );
interval_index(1) = max(1, interval_index(1));
interval_index(2) = min(length(sorted_data), interval_index(2));

% Assign output A in terms of the value in the sorted_data
A = sorted_data(interval_index)

% Assign output B
B = sum( data>A(1) & data<A(2) )

% Visualization
x = [1:length(data)];
figure;
subplot(211);
    plot(x, data, ...
         x, repmat(A(:)', length(data),1) ); grid on;
    legend('data', 'lower bound', 'upper bound');
    xlim([1 20000]);
subplot(212);
    plot(x, data, ...
         x, repmat(A(:)', length(data),1) ); grid on;
    legend('data', 'lower bound', 'upper bound');
    ylim([0, 3*10^-5]);
    xlim([1 20000]);
```

Feeding the data provided in your question into the function yields the following plot:
[image]

You may want to empirically tune the two variables in the function to obtain the desired result.

- `K1`
- `interval`

Comment: I'm really grateful with your help, Thanks a lot!!